# Python - using variable in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to change width value in the string using regex.

Width can have multiple formats, such as `width="500px"` or `width:500px` or `width=500px` (without quotes), etc..

Currently, I'm searching and replacing individually like this

```
p = re.compile('width="\w{3}')
embed_url = p.sub('width="555', embed_url)

# width:"555
p = re.compile('width:"\w{3}')
embed_url = p.sub('width:"555', embed_url)
```

Is there any way to use one regular expression and replace strings `:` or `=` accordingly?

**EDIT**

Changed the above code, so : and = is changed accordingly, instead of replacing all of them with "="

Comment: are you looking for something like `width(:|=)"?\w{3}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://regexr.com?3046q) regex:

```
width(:|=)"?\w{3}
```

it matches:

```
width="300px
width=300px
width:"300px
width:300px
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. How can I replace this with : or = accordingly?

Comment: with grouping; use this regex: `(width)(:|=)"?(\w{3})` to match the string and then replace it with: `$1$2$3`. See here http://regexr.com?304b4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `|` and grouping like this:

```
>>> p = re.compile('width(:|=)"\w{3}')
>>> print(p.sub('width="555', 'width="500px"'))
width="555px"
>>> print(p.sub('width="555', 'width:"500px"'))
width="555px"
```

If you include quotes / apostrophes in a group, you can do this:

```
>>> p = re.compile('width(:|=)("|\')\w{3}')
>>> print(p.sub('width="555', 'width:"500px"'))
width="555px"
>>> print(p.sub('width="555', 'width:\'500px"'))
width="555px"
>>> print(p.sub('width="555', 'width="500px"'))
width="555px"
>>> print(p.sub('width="555', 'width=\'500px"'))
width="555px"
```

Adding a `?` will make the previous element optional:

```
>>> p = re.compile('width(:|=)("|\')?\w{3}')
>>> print(p.sub('width="555', 'width="500px"'))
width="555px"
>>> print(p.sub('width="555', 'width=500px'))
width="555px
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I replace matched expressions with : or = accordingly?

Comment: The matched separator, either `:` or `=`, is in group 1, so you can substitute it into your replace string with `\1`. Your optional quote mark is in `\2` but only if you have a match. I would actually write that part as `(["\']?)` so group 2 would always exist even if there was no quote mark.